# live video stream from python (opencv) to c# over socket

Tags: python, c#, sockets, opencv, video-streaming

I have some video processing in OpenCV (python) that the output of python code must feed to c# code. I googled and found that it is possible via socket programming between python and c#.
I prepare the code that sends the frames from OpenCV in python as a client, but I do not have any idea to get the live video stream from c# (server). Also, is there any easier way to use the OpenCV (python) frame in c#?

Please help me!

The python code (client):

```
import cv2
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import pickle
import zlib

hostname = socket.gethostname()    
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)    
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((IPAddr , 1234))
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)



img_counter = 0

encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90]

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    result, frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)

    client_socket.sendall(bytearray(frame))
    img_counter += 1

cam.release()
```

Comment: Use standard input/output between c# and python.

Comment: There is a C# wrapper for Open CV called EmguCV http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page